# Start a Thread from different class and parameters

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I would like to start the `Thread` with methods implemented in a external class and as well as I need to pass to this method reference to some external property.

The problem is here

```
Thread t = new Thread(Agent.Activate(agentParameters, ref tcpListener));
```

Visual Studio say that `Acvivate` method should return `Thread`. But by example below it should not.

I use  this example but it does not help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setdata(v=vs.110).aspx.    Here is my code

```
    class TCPListenerManager
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener;

        public TCPListenerManager(HostListenerItem hostListenerItem)
        {
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(hostListenerItem.IP4), hostListenerItem.Port);

            for (int i = 0; i < hostListenerItem.ClientsMax; i++)
            {
                var agentParameters = new AgentParameters();
                Thread t = new Thread(Agent.Activate(agentParameters, ref tcpListener));
                t.Start();
            }
        }

    } // end of class DeviceAgent


 class Agent
    {
        [ThreadStaticAttribute]
        static int threadSpecificData;

        static public AgentParameters Parameters;

        public static void Activate(AgentParameters agentParameters, ref TcpListener tcpListener)
        {
            Parameters = agentParameters;
            threadSpecificData = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

            var socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
            if (socket.Connected)
            {
                //
                // logger.Info("Socket.Connected on" + socketParameters.HostListenerItem.Name + " " + socketParameters.HostListenerItem.Url);
            }
        }
    } // end of Agent


    class AgentParameters
    {
        public HostListenerItem HostListenerItem { get; set; }

        public AgentParameters()
        {
            HostListenerItem = new HostListenerItem();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This ClientsMax is not how it's supposed to be. Start 1 thread that accepts in a loop and starts a thread per accepted client. `if (socket.Connected)` does nothing as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass your method as a delegate to the new thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => Agent.Activate(agentParameters, ref tcpListener));
```